# what is the best way to filter out duplicate http requests from a service method in angular

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have a problem in my angular application where duplicate http calls are firing in my network tab, i know the reason why it is happening but i'm not too sure how to find a good solution seeing as this will be dynamic the api params change on different product pages.

I have a service which contains various methods one of them returns a http.get()

the problem is i'm calling this service and method in multiple components in my case its in 3 places.

when i console.log inside my method it shows my dummy message 3 times which is expected but i don't like how this is working as right now 3 http calls are made and 2 of them are the same.

How can i filter out duplicate http calls.

here is a quick mock up of what it looks like in basic terms.

```
export class  {

 getReference(productCode: string, types?: string[]): Observable<ProductReference[]> {

  const url = this.baseEndpoint.buildUrl(`products/${productCode}/references`);
   
  let params: Record<string, string> = {};
  if (types) {
   params.referenceType = types.join(',');
  }

  return this.http.get<{ references: ProductReference[] }>(url, { params })
    .pipe(
       map(response => response.references),
     );
   
 }     

}
```

component 1

```
this.ProductTestService.getReference(this.productCode, [
    ProductReferenceType.DIS_ALTERNATIVE_SIMILAR,
    ProductReferenceType.DIS_ALTERNATIVE_BETTERVALUE,
    ProductReferenceType.DIS_ALTERNATIVE_DE,
    ProductReferenceType.DIS_ALTERNATIVE_UPGRADE,
  ]).pipe(....).subscribe(....)
```

component 2

```
this.ProductTestService.getReference(this.productCode, [
    ProductReferenceType.DIS_ALTERNATIVE_SIMILAR,
    ProductReferenceType.DIS_ALTERNATIVE_BETTERVALUE,
    ProductReferenceType.DIS_ALTERNATIVE_DE,
    ProductReferenceType.DIS_ALTERNATIVE_UPGRADE,
  ]).pipe(....).subscribe(....)
```

component 3

```
this.ProductTestService.getReference(this.productCode, [
    ProductReferenceType.DIS_ALTERNATIVE_SIMILAR,
  ]).pipe(....).subscribe(....)
```

As you can see component 1 and component 2 are the same calls how do i go about stopping the duplicated http call from component 1 and component 2 without removing one of them.

Any pointers or similar experiences would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Use **RxJs shareReplay** operator with http call inside your getReference method.

```
  return this.http.get<{ references: ProductReference[] }>(url, { params })
    .pipe(
       map(response => response.references),
       shareReplay()
     );
   
 }
```